# Secure Site URL direct to wrong instance suddenly

Tags: force.com-sites

A customer has a Salesforce site with the usual two URLS

xxx.force.com
xxx.secure.force.com

Everything was working until recently.

As part of testing we did a nslookup and found the `force.com` url to be on na109 and the `secure.force.com` url to be on na130.

The page that is loading on the `force.com` url is the new page we just made the default. The page that is loading on `secure.force.com` is the old page

Another test we did was to create a new VF page with just the default text and added it to the site. On the `force.com` url the page was available. On the `secure.force.com` url the page gave **file not found**

A part of the complexity is that the page display data from a given record. Some of the older `secure.force.com` url do load the data but using the old UI and not the current UI that is loaded on the `force.com` url. This leads me to believe that the `secure.force.com` url is being directed to a sandbox instance or some copy of the production instance or something.

I am thinking an Org Migration did not update the target of the `secure.force.com` URL. This na130 instance where the secure url points to was mart of a migration on 5-3-2020 and this jives with the data that loads on the old page with the `secure.force.com` url vs the ones that don't as those records were created after the migration

We got on the phone with salesforce support to assist our customer but then SF just told us they could not help because we are an ISV with a managed package instantly assuming we were the cause. We were never able to get to the part that it was all replicated the issue with a local VF page and had the nslookup to prove it....So frustrating.

I am betting it was due to the org migration and the secure URL was just not updated

Any ideas on how to get it fixed or alternate theories?

Comment: So creating a case with support and supplying them with a reproducible test case of a local VF page doesn't get you anywhere? Perhaps have your customer create a case then and escalate to the account team if needed.

Comment: @identigral - We are doing that next. We had SF support on the phone along with the customer and as soon as they said we were a partner they immediately said they cannot help with dev support and told us to goto the developer forums....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems my assumption was correct.

After contacting SF again and getting the runaround that it was not their issue we showed them the nslookup that proved the URLs were pointing to different instance. When they saw that they escalated it and it was resolved shortly thereafter.

If you run into this situation, the quickest path to getting them to fix it is to do a nslookup on both URL's and screen shot it showing they are on different instances.